# What does you're on my hair signifies in Wedding Crashers?

Tags: dialogue, wedding-crashers

I'm always confused about the quote "Ouch, ouch, you're on my hair." in the movie *Wedding Crashers*. What does it really mean? When this quote is being translated into the Chinese version, it means "Stop touching my hair during sex." It just sounds ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen the film so I don't really know the context for the scene:

But it sounds like he's talking about how uncomfortable dating is and how awkward sex can be.

As a woman with long hair, it hurts a lot when someone pulls your hair and, when in the bedroom, it will happen occasionally, which takes a lot of the fun out of it... assuming it's not intentional...

A guy can easily trap the girl's hair between his body and the mattress, preventing the girl from moving her head and yanking the hair if she's not aware it's trapped, causing pain.

Answer (score 2):

Not to get explicit, but when a guy is on top of a girl he will usually put his weight on his elbows or hands so he's not crushing the girl.  If the girl has longer hair, his elbows/hands may be on her hair, and his weight would cause him to sink into the mattress a bit, pulling on her hair.  That's what he means, and in that sense the Chinese translation is somewhat accurate.